# Getting metadata information via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, metadata

How can I get QGIS project metadata information via PyQGIS?

QGIS version: 3.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting project title info try:

`QgsProject.instance().metadata().title()`